# Sort cells in UITableViewSource after button clicked. c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, xamarin

In my application I have 2 buttons which allows user to sort cells via "name" or "score". I've got a problem with sorting - how could i check if cells are already sorted via these 2 categories.

I am new in Xamarin and as far i did not fugure out everything.

Already I am sorting list and get common result but only for first sorting which is ascending.

Also this does not work for me :

```
            var orderedByAsc = list.OrderBy(l => l.name);
            if (list.SequenceEqual(orderedByAsc))
            {
                ascending = true;
            }



        var orderedByDsc = list.OrderByDescending(l => l.name);
        if (list.SequenceEqual(orderedByDsc))
        {
            ascending = false;
        }
```

Sorting :

```
void Sort(bool ascending, string type)
        {
            if (type.Equals("name"))
            {
                if (ascending)
                {
                    list.Sort((x, y) => x.name.CompareTo(y.name));
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Sort((x, y) => -1 * x.name.CompareTo(y.name));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (ascending)
                {
                    list.Sort((x, y) => x.score.CompareTo(y.score));
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Sort((x, y) => -1 * x.score.CompareTo(y.score));
                }
            }
        }
```

Button events :

```
nameSort.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
            {

                Sort(ascending, "name");

                tableView.ReloadData();
            };

            scoreSort.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
            {

                Sort(ascending, "score");

                tableView.ReloadData();

            };
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you said:

> Also this does not work for me :

```
var orderedByAsc = list.OrderBy(l => l.name);
if (list.SequenceEqual(orderedByAsc))
{
      ascending = true;
}

var orderedByDsc = list.OrderByDescending(l => l.name);
if (list.SequenceEqual(orderedByDsc))
{
      ascending = false;
}
```

What in particular is not working? I will assume that perhaps you do not realize that `list` itself is not changed by:

```
var orderedByAsc = list.OrderBy(l => l.name);
```

The OrderBy method returns the sorted list, leaving the original `list` unchanged, so this:

```
if (list.SequenceEqual(orderedByAsc))
```

will only evaluate to `true` if the list was already sorted before you called `list.OrderBy(l => l.name);`, IOW if there was no change after the sort. `SequenceEqual` compares the two lists to see if they are the same, but in this case they would not be, unless as noted the original `list` was already sorted by ascending.

`List.Sort` however does modify the list itself. Those lines look fine and should work, so I think the issue was that the bool `ascending` value was not getting set correctly due to what is noted above.

I hope this helps!

PS: this is not a xamarin question really, it is a .NET/Linq question.